# Spring checkbox default checked on page load

Tags: spring-mvc

In my jsp, I have the following Spring checkbox element:

```
<c:forEach var="a" items="${accountList}">
<tr>
<td width="5%">

<div align="center"><form:checkbox path="$primaryAccountId" disabled="true" 
value="${a.accountId}" onclick="someFunction()" /></div>
```

Now `primaryAccountId` in my model class is a `List<Long>`. So I am thinking how will spring decide whether on page load, the checkbox is supposed to be checked or not?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks. I located the answer:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?76388-why-lt-form-checkbox-quot-has-not-attribute-checked

Comment: You should put the answer here rather than linking to it.